# Map xml into Jasper Report tool

Tags: java, xml, excel, jasper-reports

I have a XML file which is to be converted into EXCEL(XLS). Thought of using Jasper Report tool to convert it to XLS. In the turorial it is said we need to create a JRXML template from the XML and then compile the JRXML to generate a .jasper file. I want to know how do we map xml to jrxml. Help me in creating the JRXML file from XML.

My sample xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<mig:menu-compare xmlns:mig="http://www..com//" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www..com/">
    <mig:menu-info>
        <mig:menu type="ons" name="HCOTA"/>
        <mig:menu type="ux" name="RTACOF"/>
    </mig:menu-info>
    <mig:field-details>
        <mig:fields existence="both">
            <mig:field name="taChrgOffMsg.taChrgOffCrit.Acct.foracid">
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:group-name>cota</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>cotacrit</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:control-type>Text Field</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>acctId</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT000265</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>A/c. ID</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:group-name>Rtacof</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</mig:page-name-desc>
                    <mig:control-type>FinAccountId</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>acctId$accountId</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT001251</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>A/c. ID</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                    <mig:section-structure>group1.section1.subSection1.finRow1.finCell1</mig:section-structure>
                    <mig:form>criteria</mig:form>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field name="taChrgOffMsg.taChrgOffCrit.chargeOffType">
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:group-name>cota</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>cotacrit</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:control-type>Radio Button</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>chargeOffMode</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT004530</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Charge Off Mode</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>cotaProps.chargeOffMode_MANDATORY</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:group-name>Rtacof</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</mig:page-name-desc>
                    <mig:control-type>FinRadioButtonGroup</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>chargeMode</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT003817</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Charge Off Mode</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>N</mig:mandatory>
                    <mig:section-structure>group1.section1.subSection12.finRow2.finCell4</mig:section-structure>
                    <mig:form>criteria</mig:form>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
        </mig:fields>
        <mig:fields existence="nonMap">
            <mig:field>
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:group-name>cota</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>cotacrit</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:control-type>Desc. Label</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>acctCrncy</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label></mig:label>
                    <mig:mandatory>N</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field>
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:group-name>cota</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>cotacrit</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:control-type>Desc. Label</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>acctSol</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label></mig:label>
                    <mig:mandatory>N</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field>
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:group-name>Rtacof</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>Rtacof_tranDetail_form</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:page-name-desc>Charge Off Transaction Details</mig:page-name-desc>
                    <mig:control-type>FinText</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>dtotalCollVa</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT003816</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Total Collateral Value</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:section-structure>tranDetailG1.tranDetailS1.sg_accDet.finRow32.finCell103</mig:section-structure>
                    <mig:form>tranDetail</mig:form>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
            <mig:field>
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:group-name>Rtacof</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>Rtacof_tranDetail_form</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:page-name-desc>Charge Off Transaction Details</mig:page-name-desc>
                    <mig:control-type>FinText</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>dassetClassM</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT003810</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Main/Sub Asset Classification</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:section-structure>tranDetailG1.tranDetailS1.sg_accDet.finRow32.finCell93</mig:section-structure>
                    <mig:form>tranDetail</mig:form>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
        </mig:fields>
        <mig:fields existence="ux">
            <mig:field name="taChrgOffMsg.taChrgOffCrit.Acct.acctName">
                <mig:field-type type="ux">
                    <mig:group-name>Rtacof</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>Rtacof_criteria_form</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:page-name-desc>Transaction A/c. Details</mig:page-name-desc>
                    <mig:control-type>FinAccountId</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>acctId$accountNameDesc</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT001251</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>A/c. ID</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                    <mig:section-structure>group1.section1.subSection1.finRow1.finCell1</mig:section-structure>
                    <mig:form>criteria</mig:form>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
        </mig:fields>
        <mig:fields existence="ons">
            <mig:field name="taChrgOffMsg.taChrgOffCrit.funcCode">
                <mig:field-type type="ons">
                    <mig:group-name>cota</mig:group-name>
                    <mig:page-name>cotacrit</mig:page-name>
                    <mig:control-type>Combo Box</mig:control-type>
                    <mig:ui-field>funcCode</mig:ui-field>
                    <mig:label>FLT000204</mig:label>
                    <mig:label-desc>Function</mig:label-desc>
                    <mig:mandatory>Y</mig:mandatory>
                </mig:field-type>
            </mig:field>
        </mig:fields>
    </mig:field-details>
</mig:menu-compare>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the following steps:

Step1: Design the jrxml file for the output you want in excel file.

Step2: You need a datasource to fill the jrxml file. In your case you would need XmlDataSource of JasperReport. Hence create a XmlDataSource from you xml file.

Step3: Fill the report and export it to the excel file using JasperExporter.

Comment: I've created a Java Object by which i will be able to parse through the XML but with it how do i design the JRXML?

Comment: You have to create a jrxml file, which will contain text fields and other elements. It's basically a Xml file. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_designs.htm. Go through the followed link, it should clear your picture.

Comment: thank you, infact i have installed JasperStudio to design the report. What XPath query can i use to get type = 'ons' fields as one column and type = 'ux' as other column which internally will be split into multiple columns ?    Now i'm using the query - /mig:menu-compare/mig:field-details/mig:fields. And created two datasets to fetch the 'mig:existence' and 'mig:name' but not able to map them also. Have used 'Lists' element.

Comment: Ok, I suppose you are asking for the query which will fill your report. Just a simple select * would do, but make sure you have a query which returns a result set having your fields (i.e 'ons' and 'ux').

Comment: I'm using the XML as input not from database.

Comment: http://www.packtpub.com/article/jasperreports-creating-report-from-xml-data-using-xpath . Go through this link.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm now able to start filling the report. The main XPATH query i used is 

/mig:menu-compare/mig:field-details/mig:fields[@existence = "both"]/mig:field/mig:field-type

From this i want the mig:field mig:name value 
Used this in the description of field

Comment: cont...
/mig:menu-compare/mig:field-details/mig:fields[@existence = "both"]/mig:field/@mig:name 
with the above query i'm getting only the first value for all conditions and it is not iterating.

Also, let me know how do i seperate the nodes under 'type="ux"' and 'type="ons"'

Comment: Put all your fields in detail band.

Comment: I've put it in Detail Band only. The number of iterations for that query is proper but getting same value

Comment: Also, how can i get the values for existence='ux' and existence="ons" ?

Comment: I would need to see your jrxml file, to assist you further.

Comment: Have changed the query to /menu-compare/field-details/fields[@existence = "both"]/field. And created a List with fields inside the field-type tag. I'm now able to get the values of it but it's coming twice. I'm not able to include the JRXML code here

Comment: Procedure followed is using a List with JRDatasource expression as $P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}.subDataSource("/field/field-type") and fields inside list with description as "/field/field-type[@type = "ons"]/control-type" but getting values twice.